# Issue adding events to phone calendar - Android

Tags: java, android, calendar, samsung-mobile

I have a problem working with android phone calendar, specifically with Samsung calendar S Planner.

I want to add events to phone calendar when the user clicks a button; first he has to select the date from a datePicker, then the time, from a timePicker, and finally he has to click the button that I previously mentioned.

This is not the problem, as it is working fine in all the devices I tried it. The problem is when I want to add events to Samsung default calendar (S Planner); when the user clicks the save button, the application stops working.

You can find my code below:

```
dia = datePicker.getDayOfMonth();
mes = datePicker.getMonth();
año = datePicker.getYear();
hora = timePicker.getHour();
minutos = timePicker.getMinute();

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(año,mes,dia,hora,minutos);

 if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity_programas.this,
                                new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR},
                                PERMISOCALENDARIO);
                    }

                    else if (permiso){

                        cr = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver();
                        cv = new ContentValues();
                        cv.put(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, eventoCalendario);
                        cv.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART, calendar.getTimeInMillis());
                        cv.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTEND, calendar.getTimeInMillis() + 60 * 60 * 1000);
                        cv.put(CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_ID, 1);
                        cv.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, Calendar.getInstance().getTimeZone().getID());

                        Uri uri = cr.insert(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, cv);

                        long eventID = Long.parseLong(uri.getLastPathSegment());
                        ContentValues reminders = new ContentValues();
                        reminders.put(CalendarContract.Reminders.EVENT_ID, eventID);
                        reminders.put(CalendarContract.Reminders.METHOD, CalendarContract.Reminders.METHOD_ALERT);
                        reminders.put(CalendarContract.Reminders.MINUTES, 10);

                        Uri uri2 = cr.insert(CalendarContract.Reminders.CONTENT_URI, reminders);

                        Toast.makeText(activity_programas.this, R.string.agendado, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(activity_programas.this, "Permiso no concedido", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return;
                    }
```

This code works perfectly in other devices, the problem is with S planner.

If I change the code for the one below, it works perfectly too, even in Samsung´s phones (in the code below I don´t pick the time from datePicker/timePicker, I just use the current time).

```
 if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity_programas.this,
                                new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR},
                                PERMISOCALENDARIO);
                    }

                    else if (permiso){

                        cr = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver();
                        cv = new ContentValues();
                        cv.put(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, eventoCalendario);
                        cv.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART, Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis);
                        cv.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTEND, Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis + 60 * 60 * 1000);
                        cv.put(CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_ID, 1);
                        cv.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, Calendar.getInstance().getTimeZone().getID());

                        Uri uri = cr.insert(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, cv);

                        long eventID = Long.parseLong(uri.getLastPathSegment());
                        ContentValues reminders = new ContentValues();
                        reminders.put(CalendarContract.Reminders.EVENT_ID, eventID);
                        reminders.put(CalendarContract.Reminders.METHOD, CalendarContract.Reminders.METHOD_ALERT);
                        reminders.put(CalendarContract.Reminders.MINUTES, 10);

                        Uri uri2 = cr.insert(CalendarContract.Reminders.CONTENT_URI, reminders);

                        Toast.makeText(activity_programas.this, R.string.agendado, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(activity_programas.this, "Permiso no concedido", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return;
                    }
```

I hope I was clear, sorry in advance for my English, and for my coding, I am new programming in Android.

Thank you very much,
German.

Comment: There's a classic mistake in your code: `permiso=true` sets the value of the variable `permisio` to `true`. It should be `permiso == true' or, better yet, just `permiso`.

Comment: Hello @EllenSpertus, thanks for your response. Yes, you are right! I made a mistake there, but I corrected it and the application is still stopping when I click the save button on Samsung´s phones. Any idea why it is happening? I may be doing something wrong but I can´t see what it is. Thank you!!

Comment: I responded to your post as part of experienced users trying to help new users, not out of Samsung expertise. One thing we advise is including as little code as possible. Could you trim your code down to just the few lines that don't do what you expect on a Samsung device, in contrast to the lines that do what you want? In general I've found with Android not to expect answers to *why* something doesn't work, just to find workarounds, which it sounds like you have.